# Featured image with link to post shortcode, image displaying above the post

Tags: shortcode, post-thumbnails

I have created a shortcode to display the featured image linking to the post:

```
function ck13_post_image($atts){
   extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      'ck_img_size'      => 'full'
   ), $atts));

    $show_the_image .= '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . the_post_thumbnail("$ck_img_size") . '</a>'; 
    return $show_the_image;
}

//---------------------------------------------

function register_shortcodes(){
   add_shortcode('show-post-img', 'ck13_post_image');
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes');
```

But instead of displaying the image inside the post, the image is displayed above it.

The weird thing is that the link to the post is displayed correctly inside the post, just the image is above.
Did i make some mistake? How can i make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`the_post_thumbnail` echoes its value, which doesn't work in variable assignment. Use [`get_the_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) instead.

Most WordPress API functions follow this pattern, there are typically two versions - one which will `echo` the result and another  with `get_` prepended which will `return` the result.

Comment: Yeah, my bad here, i tried get_the_post_thumbnail just without $page->ID. Thanks.